# Passing text value from one Button to another Button

Tags: android

My application is having two activities. In first activity, I have one button and in second activity I have 3 buttons and wheel view.

If I click the button from first activity it moves to second activity and if it selects any value from wheel view,that current value should be displayed in first button.

Using stored Preferences, it works fine, then if again when I select any value from wheel view that first selected value is displayed in second button and current selected item should be displayed in first button.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Hard to understand what you're talking about.

Comment: posting a flow chart may help, because your explanation is atrocious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here,

i am using getter and setter for store the first selected value in setter and get the value into second button, here my code

```
setSecondBrandValue(btnCurrentSelection.getText().toString());
    PreferenceConnector.writeString(WheelActivity.this, itemKeyName,
            wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p1).getCurrentItem()]);
```

and here i set the value to second button

```
btnSecondSelection.setText(getSecondBrandValue());
```